Override Gradle Task implementation from dependency
So I have Android Project using Gradle that uses library A with Task MPManifestTask that run every time  I build.
The issue is I'm trying to improve my build performance using gradle configuration cache. But when I run it the Gradle log some issues with the task registered.
task:app:mpProcessItDebugit-debugManifest of type com.alipay.mpaas.easy.config.MPManifestTask

invocation of Task.project at execution time is unsupported. invocation of Task.project at execution time is unsupported.

Here is what I see from the task mentioned:
    @TaskAction
    public void executeTask() throws Exception {
        Logger logger = this.getProject().getLogger();
        logger.info("======================ANDROIDMANIFEST CONVERTER START================================");
        logger.info(" start to convert" + this.appAndroidManifestFile);
    }

Based on this link, I understand that I need to change this.getProjects().getLogger() into this.getTask().getLogger() to resolve the configuration cache issue.
But how do I change task execution from a dependency? If the task is source from my own project I can just change it but the task is from dependency and the code that I quoted is read-only.
Is it possible to change the implementation of task from a dependency? And if it possible how do I do that?

You can override the action of an existing task by doing this (using Kotlin DSL):
tasks.named("MPManifestTask") {
   actions.clear()
   doLast {
      // A new task action
   }
}

Inside the doLast block the this context is the Task object. You can use this to write a new action. If the properties you need are not on the Task object and the task is of a specific type, you can cast it and access the properties in that way:
doLast {
    val task = this as InterceptedTask
    // do something with the task object
}

You could also access private properties and methods of the Task object using reflection if necessary.
